# default workspace after migration to 11g

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex

I installed 11g on my local machine and imported my data using dmp file. Now my application works fine and also I can connect to database using sql developer without any problems.

But when I try to login with apex, I don't know what to enter in `workspace` field. I used `INTERNAL` workspace with `admin` as username. But i couldn't find my tables and schemas.

I went to workspace manager and found that only `INTERNAL` workspace is defined there with a single user(admin).

How can I view and manage my existing tables using apex? (As i said above, i can do it using sql developer. But I want to do it using apex)

Comment: You migrated to 11g, from what? Or is this a new install? Did you have a prior apex installtion (since you're talking about an application)?

Comment: I had a 10g XE installation. I uninstalled it and then installed a new 11g XE installation and used `impdp` to import my data. The Java EE application has no problem and works fine with my new database installation.

Comment: Okay - but did you use/have an apex installation on your 10g? The application you refer to in your OP is a java EE app seemingly. So you are new to apex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apex is an application development environment, that happens to have some tools for managing schema objects, but for this purpose is not as powerful or easy-to-use as SQL Developer.

If you really want you could login as the administrator and create a workspace, but I'd rather use SQL Developer unless I was actually going to use Apex for its main purpose, which is building applications.

Comment: It seems that i didn't understand the main purpose of Apex and thought of it as a database development tool. So, absence of my existing schemas in apex and their presence in SQL developer would be no problem.
But i am still a bit curious if there is a way to view my tables in apex. I was able to view and edit them in my prior apex installation(In other words, I was able to use apex as a database development tool).

Comment: Yes, you can see your tables in the objects viewer. But you need a workspace first. And yes, Apex *includes* some database development tools, but its primary purpose is for application development.